# How to print to the console after every swap using any sorting algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

In my Intro to Computer Science class I am beginning to learn the basics of sorting algorithms. So far, we have gone over Bubble, Selection, and Insertion Sort.

After class today, the instructor has requested us to **"enhance" the program by adding code to print out the vector/array after every swap during the sorting**. I am at a complete loss as to how I would make this happen. I'm thinking something like :

```
if (swapped) { cout << vec << " "; }
```

but without even trying, I'm certain this wouldn't work. Any help is very much appreciated. Here's my code so far:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int> createVec(int n) {
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
       vec.push_back(rand() % 100 + 1);
    }
     return vec;
 }

void showVec(vector<int> vec) {
   for (int n : vec) {
      cout << n << " ";
   }
}

void bubbleSort(vector<int> &vec) {
   int n = vec.size();
   bool swapped = true;
   while (swapped) {
      swapped = false;
      for (int i = 1; i <= n-1; ++i) {
          if (vec[i-1] > vec[i]) {
              swap(vec[i-1], vec[i]);
              swapped = true;
          }
      }
   }
}    

 void selectionSort(vector<int> &vec) {
   int n = vec.size();
   int maxIndex;
   for (int i = 0; i <= n-2; ++i) {
     maxIndex = i;
     for (int j = i+1; j <= n-1; ++j) {
      if (vec[j] < vec[maxIndex]) {
           maxIndex = j;
          }
      }
      swap(vec[i], vec[maxIndex]);
   }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers = createVec(20);
    showVec(numbers);
    cout << endl;
    //bubbleSort(numbers);
    selectionSort(numbers);
    showVec(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add a call to `showVec` after each call to `swap`? (That's pretty much literally what the enhancement's description says...)

Comment: "After a swap" means exactly what it says. Locate a portion of code that does the swapping and insert printing code **immediately after** that.

Answer (score 0):

For example in the called function `selectionSort` substitute this statement

```
swap(vec[i], vec[maxIndex]);
```

for the following statement

```
if ( i != maxIndex )
{
    swap(vec[i], vec[maxIndex]);
    showVec( vec );
    cout << endl;
}
```

Also the function `showVec` should declare the parameter as having a constant referenced type

```
void showVec( const vector<int> &vec) {
   for (int n : vec) {
      cout << n << " ";
   }
```

}

Comment: It's funny how once you see the solution, you always realize how simple and easy it is lol thanks!